# Proper colors in Android notifications

Tags: android, android-notifications

I have a notification that contains text and ImageButtons that need to contrast the background color (white on black or black on white). If I don't manually set a color for the text, the color changes properly based on the background, but that doesn't help the ImageButtons. Also, I would ideally like to have some variance in the text color, like if the text color is black, some of it being gray. I was also hoping not to simply change the background color and instead use the device's default background color since that would probably be preferable to the user.

Comment: And the question?

Comment: @GiddyNaya "How do you change the color of text/ImageButtons to properly match the background color of the notification"